# vb.net Reference a member in a structure by name from string-variable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, structure

I have a large structure (50+ members) like this:

```
Public Structure DagDay    
    Public DayDate As Date
    Public DayEcoZone As String
    Public DayOrd As Boolean
    Public DayHelg As Boolean
    Public DayAfton As Boolean
    Public DayEvent As Boolean
    Public DayEventText As String
    Public DayIncVat As Boolean
    Public DayOmsTot As Integer
    Public DayOmsCat1 As Integer
    Public DayOmsCat2 As Integer
    Public DayOmsCat3 As Integer
    .....
End Structure
...
Dim ThisDay as DagDay
```

Now i'm trying to let a function set any specific members value in in the variable ThisDay, but I can't figure out how (else then a large select.. Case..).

```
Public Function SetValue(ByVal Field As String, ByVal value As VariantType) As Boolean

Select Case Field

            Case "DayDate"
                ThisDay.DayDate = value
            Case "DayEcoZone"
                ThisDay.DayEcoZone = value
            Case "DayOrd"
                ThisDay.DayOrd = value
            Case "DayHelg"
                ThisDay.DayHelg = value
         .....

        End Select
```

I would like to be able to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
Public Function SetValue(ByVal Field As String, ByVal value As VariantType) As Boolean

        ThisDay.[Field] = value
        Return True
End Function
```

How can I use a string variable to reference a specific member (field) in a structure?

Comment: What is `VariantType` ?

Comment: @Plutonix, I think it is a misuse of the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.VariantType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.varianttype(v=vs.110).aspx) enum.

Comment: Where are you getting the value for `Field` that you pass in?

Comment: @ Enigmativity, the value for `Field` comes from the name-property of corresponding input field (`TextBox` or `CheckBox`):es-controls that are dynamically created in one of three different `Forms`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Reflection:

I don't know the VB.NET syntax, but in C# it would be this:

```
static void SetValue(Object parent, Object newFieldValue, String fieldName) {

    FieldInfo field = parent.GetType().GetField( fieldName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
    field.SetValue( parent, newFieldValue );
}
```

Because `fieldName` is arbitrary input, you can prevent incorrect `fieldName` values by using `nameof()` to ensure you always specify a valid field-name.

Note we want `x.GetType()` instead of `typeof(x)` because we want the runtime type, not the compile-time type (which is always `Object`).

Even though you're working with a value-type `struct`, pass-by-value semantics don't apply because it's boxed as an `Object` (so it's actually passed-by-reference) so setting a field will work as though it were a `class` (reference-type).

Usage:

```
MyStruct value;
value.FieldFoo = "hello";
SetValue( value, "world", nameof(value.FieldBar) );
Assert.AreEqual( "world", value.FieldBar );
```

My VB.NET is a bit rusty, but I think this would be it:

```
Public Shared Sub SetValue(parentAs Object, newFieldValue As Object, fieldName As String)

    Dim field As FieldInfo = parent.GetType().GetField( fieldName, BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance )
    field.SetValue( parent, newFieldValue )

End Sub
```

VB.NET now has the `NameOf` operator which works the same way as C#'s.

Usage:

```
Dim value As New MyStruct
value.FieldFoo = "hello"
SetValue( value, "world", NameOf(value.FieldBar) )
Assert.AreEqual( "world", value.FieldBar )
```

Comment: Thanks a million for quick and excellent answer, testing this now.

Comment: Works like a charm! Excellent explanation! Just needs a "Imports System.Reflection" as well.. THANKS!!!